# In pycharm, how can I specify "blank lines before" a class method? (coding style)

Tags: pycharm

pycharm's default coding styles suggest 1 blank line before a class method, 
and 2 blank lines before functions.

I tried to change it in Settings> Editor> Code Style> Python> Blank Lines

But there's nothing about Maximum Blank Lines before methods.

Where can it be set?

Cat I at least disable the warning marks?

Comment: after looking at the answer, i wonder why these coding styles don't appear under "coding styles", but burried under a vague thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyCharm coding styles are based on [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

> #### [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#blank-lines) suggests,
>
> Surround **top-level function** and **class** definitions with **two blank lines**.
>
> **Method definitions inside a class** are surrounded by a **single blank line**.

It is always a good practice to stick with the style guide,

Anyway to answer the question,

You can disable *PEP 8 coding style violation warnings* to disable the warnings shown on extra blank lines, this will also disable warnings other PEP 8 coding style violations.

To disable,

Go to `File > settings > Editor > Inspections`

Search for PEP on the search box

[image: disable PEP 8 coding styles PyCharm]

Uncheck the option `PEP 8 coding style violation`, then press `ok`

Comment: "violation" -- they makes me feel like a criminal for desiring more than 1 line of space between code blocks...  shukran :)